# Add colors to existing color palette without replacing it

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme, block-editor, add-theme-support

Using `add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette' )` one can replace the color palette in the Gutenberg editor by a custom one:

```
add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette', array(
    array(
        'name' => __( 'Strong magenta', 'themeLangDomain' ),
        'slug' => 'strong-magenta',
        'color' => '#a156b4',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => __( 'Light grayish magenta', 'themeLangDomain' ),
        'slug' => 'light-grayish-magenta',
        'color' => '#d0a5db',
    ),
) );
```

My question is, is there a way to ADD colors to an existing palette (via a child theme, for example) without completely replacing it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You can merge palettes

```
$existing = get_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette' );

$new = array_merge( $existing[0], array(
    array(
        'name' => __( 'Strong magenta', 'themeLangDomain' ),
        'slug' => 'strong-magenta',
        'color' => '#a156b4',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => __( 'Light grayish magenta', 'themeLangDomain' ),
        'slug' => 'light-grayish-magenta',
        'color' => '#d0a5db',
    ),
));

add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette',  $new);
```

Comment: This solution isn't working for me - instead it's showing no default colours at all after implementing this. Not sure at what point it's failing. -- Note that I was trying to add to the default colors from Gutenberg itself, so maybe add_theme_support hadn't been called anywhere else at all yet, so maybe get_theme_support isn't returning anything. -- still I'd at least expect to get the new ones then when I array_merge. hm.

Comment: @Julix Yes, by default, Gutenberg doesn't call add_theme_support for its default color palette. This only works in child themes with parents that explicitly call add_theme_support.

Comment: just tried, but doesn't work on my child theme. get_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette' ) return false and not an array. Tried also to enable first the theme support, obviously it returns true, but no array.

Comment: You cannot just paste it in functions.php but have to wrap it in a function called by add_action() as in @Rhys's answer

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Vitatus' answer, it works best if you're using a child theme, or a plugin, that edits the above.

Assuming that the `editor-colour-palette` is called within a action with a default priority, you can call it after (usually calling `after_setup_theme` with a priority greater than 10)

e.g.

```
/**
 * Add the pink colour to the site
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpquestion357851_add_colours()
{

    $existing = get_theme_support('editor-color-palette');

    $new = array_merge($existing[0], array(
        array(
            'name'  => __('Pink', 'twentytwenty'),
            'slug'  => 'pink',
            'color' => '#ff14a7',
        ),
    ));

    add_theme_support('editor-color-palette',  $new);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'wpquestion357851_add_colours', 20);
```

You may need to see where the `add_theme_support('editor-color-palette'` is called within your theme, and make sure it is called after.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to expose the data, so it can be modified.  You can do this by adding a filter:

```php
add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette', apply_filters( 'themeLangDomain_editor_color_palette_args', array(
    array(
        'name' => __( 'Strong magenta', 'themeLangDomain' ),
        'slug' => 'strong-magenta',
        'color' => '#a156b4',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => __( 'Light grayish magenta', 'themeLangDomain' ),
        'slug' => 'light-grayish-magenta',
        'color' => '#d0a5db',
    ),
) ) );
```

Then child themes or plugins can modify the array using `add_filter` to modify the data in `themeLangDomain_editor_color_palette_arg`:

```php
add_filter( 'themeLangDomain_editor_color_palette_args', function( $palette ) {
    $palette[] = array(
        'name' => __( 'Black', 'themeLangDomain' ),
        'slug' => 'black',
        'color' => '#000000',
    );
    return $palette;
} );
```